# How can i get properties and values from type object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following json:

```
{ 
        "Values":
         { 
           "value1": "test1", 
           "value2": "teste2" 
         }  
}
```

And i have to get a specific property and value.This is my code:

```
   public MyMethod(object model)
   {
       var x = model.GetType().GetProperty("value1");
   }
```

But this is always null. How can i get this?

Comment: That's impossible to answer because it's not clear what the runtime type of `model` is. You should add the code where `model` is created. If possible, you should create a class that represents the structure of your json and replace `object model`with `YourClass model`. Then you can simply use `model.Values.Value1`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an object that contains one property named `Values`. That property is an object that contains two properties named `value1` and `value2`. In order to get `value1` and `value2`, you first have to get `Values`.

```cs
public MyMethod(object model)
{
    PropertyInfo modelProperty = model.GetType().GetProperty("Values");
    var modelValue = modelProperty.GetValue(model);
    // Get properties for value1 & value 2, then their values...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to `dynamic` type and use

```
public string MyMethod(object model)
{
   var x = ((dynamic)model).Values["value1"].Value;
   return x;
}
```

If you use asp.net core 3.0, you need to add a package reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/3.0.0) and update Startup.ConfigureServices to call AddNewtonsoftJson.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

I also find out another solution to use `JObject`, you need to add a reference  `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` for you controller.

```
public string MyMethod(object model)
{
        var data = (JObject)model;
        //save all values in items
        var items = data.SelectToken("Values").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Key == "value1")
            {
                var x = (string)item.Value;
            }
        }
 }
```